# Internet over Wi-Fi working but not over Ethernet (LAN)

Tags: wifi, time-capsule, internet, ethernet

I have run into a curious problem. When I connect my MacBook via LAN cable, the Internet doesn't work, but I can still ping other devices in my network (including the router) and also can access my network hard disk.

When I connect via Wi-Fi to the same router, the Internet works, so does anything else as it's supposed to.

I prefer using the LAN cable as it's faster and more reliable, so I really would like to solve this issue.

Please, note that I cannot restart my computer, because I'm running a very important operation, which cannot be interrupted and will take several weeks.

I hope someone will point me to the right direction as to investigating this issue.

**MacBook:**

- macOS Catalina Version 10.15.7
- MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018)
- Processor 2,6 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7
- Memory 32 GB 2400 MHz DDR4
- Startup Disk Macintosh HD
- Graphics Radeon Pro 560X 4 GB
                 Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB

**Router:** AirPort Time Capsule 802.11ac

**UPDATE # 2 as per Allan's question:**
Yes, I turn off Wi-Fi when I try to connect via Ethernet and yes, I can ping 8.8.8.8 and I also can ping other websites if I use their IP address but I cannot connect to a university VPN.

**UPDATE # 2 as per Allan's question:**
output of `ipconfig getpacket en0 | grep "domain_name_server"` with Wi-Fi turned off => nothing. en0 is my Wi-Fi interface by the way and en8 is my Ethernet, so just in case I issued the command also with en8 instead of en0:
output of `ipconfig getpacket en8 | grep "domain_name_server"` with Wi-Fi turned off => `domain_name_server (ip_mult): {192.168.1.1}`

Output of both commands with Wi-Fi on is the same => `domain_name_server (ip_mult): {192.168.1.1}`

**UPDATE # 3 as per Allan's suggestion:**
output of `nslookup apple.com 192.168.1.1`:

`;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached`

**UPDATE # 4 as per Allan's comments:**
I am able to successfully ping my router with `ping 192.168.1.1`

I am still unable to ping [www.apple.com](http://www.apple.com) or [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) nor am I able to access the Internet after setting the DNS manually with `networksetup -setdnsservers Ethernet 8.8.8.8`, wherein I replaced *Ethernet* with my the name of my LAN netowork service (found out using `networksetup -listallnetworkservices`).

With `networksetup -getdnsservers Ethernet` I get `8.8.8.8`

**UPDATE # 5 as per jksoegaard's suggestion:**
I tried manually configuring my IPv4 settings under my Ethernet connection in Network preferences, without success:

[image]

I also tried changing the default gateway through Terminal:

```
% sudo route add default 192.168.1.1
route: writing to routing socket: File exists
add net default: gateway 192.168.1.1: File exists
%
```

**The internet is still not working properly (cannot browse), though.**

Just for note, I am able to successfully ping Google, but not by its web address, but rather using its IP address:
*I had to use `nslookup` with my Wi-Fi on because otherwise (with only my Ethernet on) it wouldn't work. en0 is my Wi-Fi interface.*

```
% nslookup www.google.com
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 172.217.19.100

% sudo ifconfig en0 down % 
ping 172.217.19.10 
PING 172.217.19.10 (172.217.19.10): 56 data bytes 
64 bytes from 172.217.19.10: icmp_seq=0 ttl=113 time=127.881 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.19.10: icmp_seq=l ttl=113 time=129.241 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.19.10: icmp_seq=2 ttl=113 time=128.347 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.19.10: icmp_seq=3 ttl=113 time=128.451 ms
^C
— 172.217.19.10 ping statistics —
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0.0% packet loss 
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 127.881/128.480/129.241/0.489 ms
%
```

**UPDATE # 6 as per jksoegaard's update:**

```
networksetup -setdnsservers Ethernet 1.1.1.1
```

didn't help.
Here's the output of the other 2 commands:

```
% dig @1.1.1.1 www.google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> @1.1.1.1 www.google.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
% nslookup www.google.com

;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

%
```

**UPDATE # 7:**
Eventually, I was forced to restart the computer, which solved the problem. I have no idea what it might have been nor how to replicate the issue. I really would like to know what it caused.

Comment: Do you turn off wifi when connected via Ethernet?  Can you ping 8.8.8.8?

Comment: @Allan yes and yes, please see my update

Comment: if you can ping that 8.8.8.8 IP then Internet is working.  Can you ping www.apple.com?

Comment: @Allan Well, I can't browse any website nor connect to the VPN. I'm unable to ping www.apple.com, but I'm able to ping their IP address 2.23.109.203 (found using `nslookup www.apple.com`)

Comment: That's a DNS issue. Start by flushing your DNS cache. Type the following command:  `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`  then try pining apple.com again

Comment: @Allan I had done that already, didn't help me.

Comment: Please issue this command:  `ipconfig getpacket en0 | grep "domain_name_server"` and post the results.

Comment: @Allan check the update in my post

Comment: Do you have _anything_ different in the network settings for the two network interfaces in Settings?   They have separate entries and therefore can be configured differently.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen No, they are configured equally. This thing with my ethernet not working properly happened out of the blue. I just came home and it suddenly wasn't working as expected.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying en8 was your ethernet.  With WiFi off and Ethernet connected do `nslookup apple.com 192.168.10.1`  Let's see if that router is resolving.

Comment: @Allan please se update

Comment: Ooops...sorry for the typo.  It's supposed to be 192.168.1.1.  You're forcing nslookup to use the DNS server assigned to you.

Comment: @Allan same output

Comment: Can you ping it?  `ping 192.168.1.1`

Comment: @Allan Yes, I can ping successfully all the devices in my local area network.

Comment: For whatever reason, the DNS server that your DHCP server assigned you (they can and are one in the same) is not responding to DNS requests.  It could a be a firewall issue on the router.  Let's try manually adding a DNS entry `networksetup -setdnsservers Ethernet 8.8.8.8` or you can go into the Advanced Tab of Network Preferences and add it there.  See if you can now ping apple.com or google.com or browse the network.

Comment: If "Ethernet" is not the right name, you can get the list of services with the command `networksetup -listallnetworkservices`

Comment: @Allan see update 4

Comment: What do you get with `networksetup -getdnsservers Ethernet`?

Comment: @Allan just 8.8.8.8

Comment: Please no not post unnecessary images of Terminal output. Simply copy and paste from Terminal and then use code formatting.

Comment: Ok...a couple of things.  This is a DNS issue, not a routing issue.  If you can ping things with an IP address, then your routing works fine.  DNS just gives you a name to translate to IP, it goes Mac sends hostname → DNS sends IP info back → Mac routes traffic to  host based on IP → host responds back → Mac.  Let's try configuring your Ethernet manually.  Easiest way is to go into Network settings and and change from "DHCP" to "Manually Assigned"  In the DNS field, put 8.8.8.8.

Comment: Also, by any chance do you have a proxy configured?  Issue the command `networksetup -getwebproxy Ethernet`

Answer (score 1):

According to your question you can access local network devices when on cabled LAN. You have set your DNS server to 8.8.8.8, but still cannot lookup names.

You're able to ping your router at 192.168.1.1 and other local devices, but not internet servers such as apple.com or google.com.

This suggests to me that your problem is that the default gateway is set incorrectly. Fix it this way:

1. Open System Preferences > Network
2. Choose the Ethernet port in the list on the left
3. Ensure the Router field is set to: 192.168.1.1

If it is setup to use DHCP, take a note of your IP address, subnet mask and router addresses, and then change the setting "Configure IPv4" to "Manually" and enter the same values - however note that router should be set to 192.168.1.1.

After applying, you should be able to access web sites and ping servers on the Internet.

You can also try changing this from the Terminal by running:

```
route add default 192.168.1.1
```

**UPDATE:**

Your new update indicates now that you can ping outside IPs successfully, but not when using domain names. This means this is a DNS issue, and not a routing issue.

Change the DNS server IP like this in the Terminal:

networksetup -setdnsservers Ethernet 1.1.1.1

Then check if web sites start working. If not, run these two commands in the Terminal:

```
dig @1.1.1.1 www.google.com
nslookup www.google.com
```

The output should tell if it is at all possible to lookup DNS via 1.1.1.1 (if not, you probably have some sort of firewall or filtering issue) - or it is due to the specified DNS server not actually being used at all.

Comment: Did not help, please see my update.

Comment: @yssup Your update indicates now that you _can_ ping outside IPs successfully... then this is only a DNS issue, and not a routing issue. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Please see update.

Comment: @yssup This indicates that there's something filtering your DNS requests. Try connecting to WiFi and check in System Preferences => Network which IP-address the DNS server has when connected via WiFi. Then use the same DNS IP address when you're cabled network. Did that work? ... I assume you have some kind of "safe dns" filter enforced by an ISP, or an employer, or similar.

Comment: My DNS server address is 8.8.8.8 under the DNS tab in the Advanced window of my Wi-Fi network settings.

Comment: Do you have any antivirus or anti malware software installed? Are you on a VPN? What make and model is your router and/or access point? What kind of internet connection do you have? (Cellular, fiber, ADSL?)

Comment: No antivirus nor antimalware. I am not on VPN. My router is Time Capsule 5th generation. My internet connection type is a broadband fiber, I guess. The point is that everything had been working fine until I came home a couple of days ago and suddenly this problem began.

Comment: Which country are you in? - The ping times you have are really high - which could be normal some places, but seem quite weird. What are your ping times when you're on WiFi? - Have you tried with a different network cable?

Comment: Slovakia I am in. The ping times are similar when on Wi-Fi. Different network cable I have not.

Comment: What happens when you run this: ping -c 1500 23.78.44.61

Comment: it pings nicely, but with high ping times, like 100, 50, 200, etc.

Comment: What about: ping -c 1500 1.1.1.1

Comment: Seems weird that you can ping everything just fine with both small and large packets - but you cannot do a DNS lookup. Do you have Little Snitch or something like that installed?

Comment: The other pings works fine too, ping times cca 120, 70, 8, 60... I don't have little snitch. I'm starting to think this will turn out to be a bug in macOS.

Comment: I very much doubt that it is a bug in macOS. Have you actually tried rebooting by the way?  The next step I think would be to run "tcpdump -n -i en8" and do a DNS lookup, and check what comes up.

Comment: After doing the tcpdump, how do I do the DNS lookup or would do you mean thereby?

Comment: You run the tcpdump command in one window, then in another window you run "dig @1.1.1.1 www.google.com" like before. Type Ctrl-C to stop the tcpdump command afterwards. We should move to chat instead.